# Improve Coroutine Request type safety

Tags: haskell, coroutine, type-safety

Working with [monad-coroutine](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-coroutine) package I have some coroutine doing a lot of work and it needs some input from time to time:

```
Coroutine (Request SomeRequest SomeResponse) (State MyState) a
```

where

```
data SomeRequest
  = GetImportantData Int
  | OtherImportantStuff Float
  | SomethingElse (Vector Int)
  | ...

data SomeResponse
  = ImprtantData (Vector Float)
  | ImportantStuff Int
  | ...
```

As you can see for each entry in `SomeRequest` I have a respective entry in `SomeResponse`.

During the runtime of this coroutine I have something like this:

```
...
ImportantData info <- request (GetImportantData 666)
...
```

Now I'm afraid that this approach is not good because what I want is to make sure that whenever I request important data with `GetImportantData` the only possible response is `ImportantData` and nothing else. With my current approach I have to pattern match every single time I make a request (to make sure that the input is actually what I want).

Any way I can improve the design/approach to make sure that for `GetImportantData` I get `ImportantData` back only, for `OtherImportantStuff` I get `ImportantStuff` only, etc ?

Comment: Turn each constructor into its own type, and use a type class with an associated data or type family.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the monad-coroutine-provided

```
data Request request response x = Request request (response -> x)
```

define your own suspension type

```
data MySuspension x
  = GetImportantData Int (Vector Float -> x)
  | GetOtherImportantStuff Float (Int -> x)
  | ...
  deriving (Functor)
```

Or you can use a GADT

```
data MyRequest r where
  GetImportantData :: Int -> MyRequest (Vector Float)
  GetOtherImportantStuff :: Float -> MyRequest Int
  ...
```

and a corresponding suspension type involving an existential, as in the [operational](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational-0.2.3.2/docs/Control-Monad-Operational.html) package. (monad-coroutine just provides a free monad transformer, and operational provides a slightly different kind of free monad transformer. `Coroutine MySuspension m r` is essentially the same as `ProgramT MyRequest m r`.)

Answer (score 2):

Phantom types and GADTs may help you achieve more type safety here.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import qualified Data.Vector as V

data Important
data SomethingElse

data Request a where
  GetImportantData :: Int -> Request Important
  OtherRequest :: Float -> Request SomethingElse

data Response a where
  ImportantData :: V.Vector Int -> Response Important
  OtherResponse :: Int -> Response SomethingElse

-- a typical use case
controller :: Request Important -> Response Important
controller (GetImportantData n) = ImportantData $ V.singleton n

-- or, more generally
controller' :: Request a -> Response a
controller' (GetImportantData n) = ImportantData $ V.singleton n

-- error: Couldn't match type 'Important' with 'SomethingElse'
badController :: Request a -> Response a
badController (GetImportantData n) = OtherResponse n
```

`Request a` and `Response a` are phantom types because the type parameter `a` has nothing to do with the underlying values (e.g. `Int` in `GetImportantData`) . Phantom type is widely used for ensuring type safety.

The language extension `GADTs` permits explicit type declaration of a constructor, make it easy to distinguish between constructors of a data type.

Instead of

```
data Foo = Bar | Qux
```

where `Bar` and `Qux` both have type `Foo`, with `GADTs` one can define

```
data Foo a where
  Bar :: Foo Int
  Qux :: Foo Float
```

by doing so `Bar` and `Qux` have different types.

There are some brilliant tutorials about this topic on WikiBooks and Haskell wiki.

- https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT